# HTMLOptionElement: label vs text

Tags: javascript, html

`<option>`s seemingly have 2 ways of setting the text content? `.label` and `.text`. `label` seems to take precedence over `text` but otherwise seems to behave the same.

```js
const sel = document.getElementById('sel')
console.log(sel.children[0].text)
sel.children[0].text = "foo"
```

```html
  <select id="sel">
    <option label="bar">world</option>
  </select>
```

Does this serve a purpose? Does one work better for screen readers? Tooltips?

Comment: There are often a lot of different ways to achieve the same thing in JS and HTML

Comment: From [the docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/option#attr-label)... _"This attribute is text for the label indicating the meaning of the option. If the `label` attribute isn't defined, its value is that of the element text content."_

Comment: @CertainPerformance Perhaps, but HTML supports the `label` attribute plus the content, and JS supports `.label` and `.text`. So both APIs support both properties.

Comment: @Phil Right, but functionally, what does that mean? Sure the "label is the meaning of the option" but so is the text if they behave identically?

Comment: Answering your question with a canonical, unopinionated answer would require the input of an author of [the specification](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/form-elements.html#the-option-element). Given that's unlikely to happen, this falls under the umbrella of [Is asking "why" on language specifications still considered as "primarily opinion-based" if it can have official answers?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/323334/283366)

Comment: @Phil I'll remove the "why" then. I'm not so much interested in the philosophy here, just the functional differences.